# Allow use of Access application with tables linked to SQL Server without giving users server roles?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an `Access 2013` application with tables linked to `SQL Server 2008 R2`.  When testing with a user, I gave him db_datareader and db_datawriter roles for the database.

I got this error:

> Connection failed: SQLState '28000' SQL Server Error: 18456
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user
>   'xxxxx'

When I added sysadmin server role, he was able to use the application.

How can I allow users to use the app without giving them server roles?

Comment: Are you using Windows authentication for SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows authentication.

Comment: When you create a new login is it not assigned the `public` Server Role by default?

Comment: You need to create the login at server level and then add the user to the database with the database roles you described. No roles at server level are needed. The connect permissions are given by default.

Comment: Your app can contain (preferably hidden) credentials to the database and not use the user's credentials. This can usually be achieved by linking the tables through code, rather than with the GUI.

Comment: @SunKnight0 You can't use that if you want to use database-level roles based on the users AD login afaik

Comment: @Gord, it is, but with only the public server role I get the error.

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth my understanding s that the OP want to avoid exactly that. Create a database application that every AD user can use without any per user setup needed on the SQL server.

Comment: @JodyT, I created the user at the server level.  Under user mapping, I l selected the database and added db_datareader and db_datawriter. That  results in the error.  When I add the  sysadmin server role, the error goes away.

Comment: I'm testing this with one user, but I want to create a security group.

Comment: Can you check if [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555332/login-failed-for-user-error-message-when-you-log-on-to-sql-server) contains a solution for your problem?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the responses.  It turns out that this issue is caused by the security setup  for this server to adhere to DoD requirements.

Comment: So what was your solution?

Comment: I was authorized to give them a server role for this prototype.